# Web scrape Google search results using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, information-retrieval

My goal is to web scrape Google search results using BeautifulSoup. I am using Anaconda Python and use Ipython as the IDE console. Why don't I get an ouptput when run the following command?

```
def google_scrape(query):
    address = "http://www.google.com/search?q=%s&num=100&hl=en&start=0" % (urllib.quote_plus(query))
    request = urllib2.Request(address, None, {'User-Agent':'Mosilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11'})
    urlfile = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    page = urlfile.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

    linkdictionary = {}

    for li in soup.findAll('li', attrs={'class':'g'}):
        sLink = li.find('a')
        print sLink['href']
        sSpan = li.find('span', attrs={'class':'st'})
        print sSpan

    return linkdictionary

if __name__ == '__main__':
    links = google_scrape('english')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are never adding anything to linkedDictionary

```
def google_scrape(query):
    address = "http://www.google.com/search?q=%s&num=100&hl=en&start=0" % (urllib.quote_plus(query))
    request = urllib2.Request(address, None, {'User-Agent':'Mosilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11'})
    urlfile = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    page = urlfile.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

    linkdictionary = {}

    for li in soup.findAll('li', attrs={'class':'g'}):
        sLink = li.find('a')
        sSpan = li.find('span', attrs={'class':'st'})

        linkeDictionary['href'] = sLink['href']
        linkedDictionary['sSpan'] = sSpan

    return linkdictionary

if __name__ == '__main__':
    links = google_scrape('english')
```

Comment: What should I be adding to it?

Comment: whatever you want to return

Comment: I want to web scrape the google results I get for the word 'english'. Can you please how to edit this code to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem as [Cody Bouche](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32274783/15164646) mentioned is that nothing has been adding to the `dict()`.
In my opinion, you'll have hard times updating your dict if you haven't change `{}`(dict) to `[]`(array).

Appending to array is much simpler (*note: I could be wrong here, it's just a personal opinion from previous experience*).

To make it work in a simple maner, you need to change **dict** to **array** `{} --> []` and then use `.append({})` to append to `list()`

Code and example in the [online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Link-and-append-to-the-dictlist):

```py
def google_scrape(query):
    html = requests.get(f'https://www.google.com/search?q={query}', headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    data = []

    for container in soup.findAll('div', class_='tF2Cxc'):
        title = container.select_one('.DKV0Md').text
        link = container.find('a')['href']

        data.append({
          'title': title,
          'link': link,
        })
        print(f'{title}\n{link}')

    print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))

google_scrape('english')

# part of the outputs:
'''
English language - Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language
[
  {
    "title": "English language - Wikipedia",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language"
  },
]
'''
```

If you still want to append to `dict()` then this is one of the ways of approaching this (*only part of the for loop shown*):

```py
for container in soup.findAll('div', class_='tF2Cxc'):

    data_dict = {}

    title = container.select_one('.DKV0Md').text
    link = container.find('a')['href']
    # creates title key and assigns title value
    data_dict['title'] = title
    # creates link key and assigns link value
    data_dict['link'] = link

    print(json.dumps(data_dict, indent = 2))

# part of the output:
'''
{
  "title": "Minecraft Official Site | Minecraft",
  "link": "https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/"
}
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing using [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

Essentially, it's doing the same thing as the code above, but you don't to figure out how to do certain things or trying to understand how to scrape certain element, it's already done for the end-user with a `JSON` output so the only thing that needs to be done is to iterate over a `JSON` and get the desired output.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import json

params = {
  "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "minecraft",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results['organic_results']:
  print(json.dumps(result, indent = 2, ensure_ascii = False))

# part of the json output:
'''
{
  "position": 1,
  "title": "Minecraft - Aplikasi di Google Play",
  "link": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mojang.minecraftpe&hl=in&gl=US",
  "displayed_link": "https://play.google.com › store › apps › details › id=co...",
  "rich_snippet": {
    "top": {
      "detected_extensions": {
        "skor": 46,
        "suara": 4144655,
        "us": 749
      },
      "extensions": [
        "Skor: 4,6",
        "‎4.144.655 suara",
        "‎US$7,49",
        "‎Android",
        "‎Game"
    ]
  }
}
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.